# How to make a matrix from a given vector by using for loop

Tags: r

I am trying to make a `$n\times 4$` matrix by retrieving the `n-th four` elements in a given vector. Since I am new to `R`, don't know how to use loop functions properly.

My code is like

```
x<-runif(150,-2,2)
x1<-c(0,0,0,0,x)
for (i in 0:150)
 {ai<-x1[1+i,4+i]
 }
```

However, I got: `Error in x1[1 + i, 4 + i] : incorrect number of dimensions.`

I also want to combine these `ai` into a matrix, and each `ai` will be the `i+1-th` row of the matrix. Guess I should use the cbind function?

Any help will be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: I guess you got the error because your input data is `vector` and the indexing ie. `[1+i, 4+i]` is for matrices/data.frames etc.  Could you show the expected result?

Comment: What would the expected result look like?

Comment: @akrun @ Roman Luštrik

Answer (score 0, accepted):

May be this helps:

```
n <- length(x1)-1
res <- sapply((4:n)-3, function(i) x1[(i+3):i])
dim(res)
#[1]   4 150
```

Comment: @ Roman Luštrik @akrun Let $X1=(0,0,0,0,a1,....,a150)$, then my matrix is like row1 = (0,0,0,0), row2=(a1,0,0,0),row3=(a2,a1,0,0),row4=(a3,a2,a1,0),row5=(a4,a3,a2,a1),....,row150=(a149,a148,a147,a146). So n-th row of the matrix consists of the n-th four elements of the vector X1, and it is in reverse order. Also a150 is left out. The dimension of the matrix is $x\times 150$.

Comment: I tried  n<-length(x1)-1  res<-sapply((4:n)-3,function(i) x1[(i+3):i]), and it worked somehow. Thanks!

Comment: @Xst67 Yes, I guess that should do it.  I was away from the computer.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this directly with the `matrix` command:

```
x <- 1:36

xmat<-matrix(x,nr=9,byrow=TRUE)
```