# Drop k first rows of a matrix by using loop function

Tags: r, matrix

I have created a matrix called col of dimension 150x4.

Now I want to create a 150x600 matrix by binding (col,col1,....,col149), where colk is created by replacing the first k rows of col by zeros.

My code for col1 is

`c1<-col[-1,]
  row<-(0,0,0,0)
  col1<-rbind(row,c1)`

However, It will be really hard if If k=149. I guess a loop function is required. Also, col1 that I created doesn't look like a matrix. When I print it in R, there's no row numbers.

Since I am new to R, don't know how to do these things in R.

My code for col is col<-t(res),which can be seen in
[How to make a matrix from a given vector by using for loop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26297509/how-to-make-a-matrix-from-a-given-vector-by-using-for-loop)

Can anyone help me address this issue? Thanks in advance !

Answer (score 0):

May be this helps:

```
res1 <-  cbind(colN,do.call(`cbind`, lapply(1:149, function(i) {
                        rN <- matrix(rowN[col(colN[1:i,,drop=FALSE])], ncol=4)
                        rbind(rN, colN[-(1:i),]) 
                       })))

  dim(res1)
 #[1] 150 600
```

#### data

From the link

```
set.seed(25)
x<-runif(150,-2,2)
x1<-c(0,0,0,0,x)
n <- length(x1)-1
res <- sapply((4:n)-3, function(i) x1[(i+3):i])
colN <- t(res)
rowN <- rep(0,4)
```