# Combine N matrices using loop funciton

Tags: r, matrix

I have some trouble in combining `90` matrices into a single matrix by using a loop function. I created a matrix called "col", and created the remaining `89` matrices by using the code below

```
for (k in 1:89){
  col[k,]<-row
  colk<-col
  }
```

The dimension of col is `90x4`. And since colk is created by replacing the first k rows of col by `(0,0,0,0)`. i.e drop the first k rows.

Now I want to combine the combine these `90` matrices into a single matrix of dimension `90x360`. The code I am using is

```
col0<-col
 for(k in 0:89)
 {
  matrixreview<-cbind(colk)
 }
dim(matrixreview)
## [1] 90  4
```

However, as we can see, the dimension of matrixreview is 90x4 rather than 90x360. So there is definitely some problem when I use the for loop. Since I am new to R, don't know how to solve this problem. Anyone can give me some help? Thanks in advance.

Comment: If the matrices are in a list, you could do `res <- do.call(cbind,lapply(1:90, function(i) matrix(sample(0:5, 90*4, replace=T), ncol=4)));  dim(res)#[1]  90 360`

Comment: I guess this question is similar to the one you asked earlier http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26467260/drop-k-first-rows-of-a-matrix-by-using-loop-function/26778234#26778234  I posted a solution there.